# Determining big oh time complexity

Tags: asymptotics

I am practicing questions in which I need to determine the big oh time complexity for a given piece of code. I have attempted the first 3 questions. Could anyone please confirm if the answers are  correct?

Also, I am not sure how to calculat the big oh time complexity of the code in the 4th question. Could someone please explain how to calculate it?

Thank you

1:

```
sum, i = 0, 0 
while i**2 < n:
    sum = sum + i 
    i += 2
```

O(n^(1/2))

2.

```
i, j, sum =1,1,0 
while i < n**3:
    while j < n: 
        sum=sum+ i
        j += 1 
    i=i+n
```

O(n^3)

3.

```
i, sum = 0, 0 
while i *2 < n:
    sum = sum + i 
    i=i+1
```

O(log(n))

4.

```
i, sum =0,0 

while i < 3 * n:
    if i %2 == 0:
        j = 1
        while j < n:
            sum = sum + j
            j=j*2 
    else :
        j = 1
        while j < n:
            sum = sum * j
            j += (n // 5) 
    i=i+5
```

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Comment: You wrote four questions but only three answers.